# GNOME 3 Different menu options for root and user

Tags: gnome3, gui

I built GNOME 3.16 on my LFS system. I have a strange configuration issue where my root and normal user see different items in the applications menu.
Here's a screenshot of gedit's menu options as user:
[image]
This is the screenshot as root:
[image]
As you can see, root sees 4 more items (preferences, help, about, quit). My question is how do I make these options available to normal users. I tried going through the everything in dconf-editor, but nothing helped. Same issue with Epiphany and other GNOME applications.
However, when I stop gdm and open gedit from a xterm, the menu items are complete. So, it's some other GNOME component that is preventing the listing.
I tried going through pretty much everything in dconf-editor that seemed it might help, and also changed between 2-3 different themes, but nothing seemed to work. I've been at this for days now and most of what I found on the net was not applicable to my issue.
Can someone please tell me where to look for the settings or is this something by design? Let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is go to Tweak Tool -> Top Bar -> Show Application Menu = Off.
Apparently, the application menu items are in the Top Bar now. But if the Top Bar is running under a different or not available, it shows the preferences with the regular menu items. Hence, the two different views for root and user.